# Which movie did top-to-bottom credits first?

Tags: first-appearance, credits, se7en, kiss-me-deadly

One of the many notable things about modern film-noir *[Seven](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114369/)* was its reverse credits (scrolling top to bottom, the opposite to the expected direction).

I recently rewatched the brilliant 1950's film-noir *[Kiss Me Deadly](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0048261/)* where the credits do the same, disturbing, thing.

Was *Kiss Me Deadly* first to disturb its audience this way?

Comment: Interesting question but I don't see how this could be "disturbing"  if the credits were going a different direction.

Comment: @TylerShads Well I can confirm that it disturbed me. I think because it breaks the rules that a viewer expects and this makes any viewer uncomfortable. This is clearly the intent in Seven, for example. I was surprised at how odd it seemed in a '50s movie.

Comment: The movie Stoker also has reversed credits. Probably the most, but not the only, disturbing thing about the 2013 film.

Comment: I know that REPO MAN did it in 1984 ...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to IMDb **there are only 17 movies** (including shorts) that uses this rolling down credits technique, the earliest being just the one you used as example: [Kiss Me Deadly (1955)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0048261/).

In the list of movies that match this request there's also, as you mentioned, [Seven (1999)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114369/).

Recently, the movie [Next (2007)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0435705/) used this approach, making it the last to do so thus far.

If you consider shorts, there are only two:

- [Stocking Stuffers (2001)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0765846/)
- [Beneath the Veneer of a Murder (2010)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1806809/)

Here's the [IMDb link](http://www.imdb.com/keyword/credits-rolling-down/?sort=release_date) to the movie list.

Comment: Awesome! So glad to see an answer this one was bugging me!

Comment: @Advicer I second the awesome. And I now know that another movie favourite of mine, Repo Man, shares more than a McGuffin with Kiss Me Deadly!